# Display stored data after rotation in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, rotation, android-recyclerview, android-volley, parcelable

Here is my case. I retrieve some data from a database with the help of Volley Library. Everything works fine. However when I rotate the screen,the webservice is running again,and I don't want this to happen. So here are the steps I followed.

1) In my model object I implement the `Parcelable` interface which contains the data I want to store.

2) I override the onSaveInstanceState method to store the data when I rotate the screen. That part is working.

```
 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putParcelableArrayList(CLUB_NEWS,listItemsList);
 }
```

3) Next I am restoring those data after rotating the phone,by using that line which works fine too:).

```
 listItemsList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(CLUB_NEWS);
```

As I said the webservice is running again after rotation. I fixed this by reading single values for various webservices. But when it comes to recyclerview I am bit confused. Here is my code.

**model object**

```
public class ClubNewsObject implements Parcelable{
String title;
public ClubNewsObject(){

}
public ClubNewsObject(Parcel in) {
    title = in.readString();
    article = in.readString();
    image = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<ClubNewsObject> CREATOR = new Creator<ClubNewsObject>() {
    @Override
    public ClubNewsObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ClubNewsObject(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ClubNewsObject[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ClubNewsObject[size];
    }
};

public void setArticle(String article) {
    this.article = article;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getArticle() {
    return article;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

String article;
String image;

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeString(article);
    dest.writeString(image);
}
```

}

**ClubNewsFragment**

```
public class ClubNewsFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TAG = "ManuApp";
private static final String IMAGE_URL = "xxxxxx" ;
private static final String CLUB_NEWS ="Club news" ;
private ArrayList<ClubNewsObject> listItemsList;
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ClubNewsAdapter adapter;
private Parcelable mListState;
public ClubNewsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_club_news, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    listItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.club_news_recycler_view);

    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    adapter = new ClubNewsAdapter(getActivity(), listItemsList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        listItemsList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(CLUB_NEWS);

    }

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState==null) {
        updateClubNewsList();
    }
}

public void updateClubNewsList() {

    listItemsList.clear();

    //declare the adapter and attach it to the recyclerview

    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonArrayRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, Config.URL_CLUB_NEWS, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            //hidePD();

            // Parse json data.
            // Declare the json objects that we need and then for loop through the children array.
            // Do the json parse in a try catch block to catch the exceptions
            try {



                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject post = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    ClubNewsObject item = new ClubNewsObject();
                    item.setTitle(post.getString("title"));
                    item.setImage(IMAGE_URL + post.getString("images"));
                    item.setArticle(post.getString("article"));


                    listItemsList.add(item);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Update list by notifying the adapter of changes
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //hidePD();
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putParcelableArrayList(CLUB_NEWS,listItemsList);
}

}
```

I think all trick is inside the `onCreateView(...)` method of the fragment where I successfully restore all the data.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Theo.

**EDIT**

On my adapter code I have put an extra method called setClubNews.

```
public class ClubNewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClubNewsRowHolder> {

private List<ClubNewsObject> clubNewsObjectList;
private Context mContext;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private int focused = 0;

public ClubNewsAdapter(Activity activity, List<ClubNewsObject> clubNewsObjectList){
    this.clubNewsObjectList = clubNewsObjectList;
    this.mContext = activity;
}
@Override
public ClubNewsRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.club_news_row,null);

    final ClubNewsRowHolder holder = new ClubNewsRowHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ClubNewsRowHolder holder, int position) {
    final ClubNewsObject listItems = clubNewsObjectList.get(position);
    holder.itemView.setSelected(focused==position);

    holder.getLayoutPosition();

    mImageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    holder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(listItems.getImage(),mImageLoader);
    holder.thumbnail.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.reddit_placeholder);

    holder.name.setText(Html.fromHtml(listItems.getTitle()));
    holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String title = listItems.getTitle();
            String article = listItems.getArticle();
            String image = listItems.getImage();
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Extras.class);
            i.putExtra("title",title);
            i.putExtra("article",article);
            i.putExtra("image",image);
            mContext.startActivity(i);
            //Toast.makeText(mContext,"You clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,WebActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("url",postUrl);
            // mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != clubNewsObjectList?clubNewsObjectList.size() :0 );
}

public void setClubNews(ArrayList<ClubNewsObject> clNews) {

      clubNewsObjectList = clNews;
    //update the adapter to reflect the new set of movies
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}
```

And then I called it after restoring the data inside the onCreateView.

```
if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        ArrayList<ClubNewsObject> items =   
        savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(CLUB_NEWS);
        adapter.setClubNews(items);
    }else{
        updateClubNewsList();
    }
```

But still the webservice is running after the device's rotation.

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate your screen. Your activity state is stored and will be passed to your fragment's
    onActivityCreated method. So what you may do if check if the CLUB_NEWS key exists in the Bundle and that it the Bundle is not null.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityCreated(Bundle state){
    if(state != null){
        //fill adapter with data from
       // state using CLUB_NEWS key

   }else{

       //fill adapter with data from
       // web service
   }
```

}

PS; Couldnt type a lot, on my mobile

Comment: This is what I don't understand. How to fill the adapter from CLUB_NEWS key!

Comment: Where is your adapter code? Usually for that kind of data you may subclass ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I fixed it. I had to save the state of the fragment in my main activity:).